# unexpected T_CONST in CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, oauth

I'm using [this](https://github.com/adoy/PHP-OAuth2) oAuth library, as recommended by FreeAgent (the API I'm hooking in to).

I've got the code working OK in a standalone file, but when included in my controller I get the following error:

`PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONST`

After 10 minutes of Googling the only reference I can find to this issue is due to using PHP4, but I'm running 5.3.6, so it's not that. Is it a scope/nesting issue?

The code looks roughly like this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Prop extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
public function testoauth()
{

    require( site_url('oauth/client.php') );
    require( site_url('oauth/GrantType/IGrantType.php') );
    require( site_url('oauth/GrantType/AuthorizationCode.php') );

    const CLIENT_ID     = 'redacted';
    ...
```

And the error is trigger on that first instance of `const`.

Edit: OK so I have clarification that the `constant` cannot exist within a function. So how the hell do I do this in CodeIgniter then? The only way I know how to handle `config` files wouldn't be any more compatible with constants than functions would.

Comment: Are these 3 `  at the end of the first line intentional?

Comment: The ones after the ellipses? um no, that's just how you close code in SO, they're there by accident...

Comment: You cannot declare a constant within a function of a class. It must be declared prior to any initiation, and cannot be changed, that is why it is called a `CONSTANT`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - I figured it may be something along these lines. So the correct course of action would be… ? I'm not attempting to change it, it is free to be constant.

Comment: `class Prop extends CI_Controller { const CLIENT_ID = 'redacted'; public function....`

Comment: Ah, so before any functions are declared? (I'm thinking this is probably best handled in a configuration file anyway, but just to make sure)

Comment: The order doesn't matter, what matters is that you cannot modify or declare a constant within a function, that's it.

Comment: Yup, that's what I wanted clarifying, cheers English bot :)

Comment: But if anyone has any info on how to actually do this in CI I;'d be grateful. Putting the constants outside of the function scope in CI seems to break things.

Answer (score 0):

Two things needed to be done here.

The first was the problem @Ohgodwhy pointed out, that constants cannot exist within functions.

As it turns out CodeIgniter has its own home for constants, in `application/config/constants.php`

So they ended up looking like this, in the bottom of that file:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| oAuth
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

define('CLIENT_ID',              'redacted');
...
```

Secondly I was using the `site_url()` function for the `require`, which was unnecessary and caused a new error of its own.